# Attach File in Form Data with just URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I am trying to upload some images into my current CMS and they have an API which accept mulitpart/form-data so that I can upload images directly from an API. I don't want to have to download these images to a local directly on my computer and then use fs.createReadStream in order to add the file. I would rather take an image url and add that into the form data so I don't need to save the image locally. Is there a way to achieve this. I was using the request library to do something like the following. I saw in an example that you could pass form data request and then the URL to return the image binaries. It does seem to work but I think I am running into more issues because of this way. Anyone know of a better solution.

```
  const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: fileAPIURL,
      qs: {
          access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      formData: {
          folder_paths: 'Blog_Media',
          image: request(featuredImage)
      },
      json: true
  }
```

Comment: The server expect to get the file content. If you send the file information such as URL instead, the server should do other thing to get the content by the information client sent. If the client only do pass the file in this case, you can totally modify the server to download the file itself.

Comment: Would that mean that I can just pass formData the image url and then the server will download the image based on that url that I passed in the form data object